# Upgrade Python 3.2 to Python 3.4 on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, apt

I have Python 3.2 installed by default on my Raspbian Linux, but I want Python 3.4 (`time.perf_counter`, `yield from`, etc.). Installing Python 3.4 via `apt-get` is no problem, but when i type `python3` in my shell I still get Python 3.2 (since `/usr/bin/python3` still links to it). Should I change the Symlink, or is there a better was to do this?

Comment: edit your .bashrc and export the path

Answer (score 3):

You **must not** change the symlink as there might be Debian utility scripts that depend on the `python3` being Python 3.2 or having a particular library installed. There are a multitude of command line utilities that depend on particular version on Debian and derived versions; for example on my Ubuntu, there are scripts in `/usr/bin` with `python3` on shebang; there the `python3` means *that* Python 3 that the operating system keeps the current. If you install Python 3 by hand, it is not the one that operating system thinks is useable as `python3` for all scripts. An example from my Ubuntu 14.10 system:

```
[/usr/bin]% python3 bluez-list-devices  
[/usr/bin]% python3.4 bluez-list-devices  
[/usr/bin]% python3.3 bluez-list-devices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bluez-list-devices", line 3, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
[/usr/bin]% head -n 1 bluez-list-devices
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

If you change the symlink at your own decision, at worst you can make the system unbootable.

Just use `python3.4` as the command, or use a virtual environment.

Comment: Why shohuld they depend on `python3` being Python 3.2? - Python 3.4 is backwards compatible.

Comment: it is backwards compatible, but there are specific libraries that are installed for Python 3.2, and not 3.4. Debian distros use Python internally too.

Comment: Python native extensions which are linked against Python 3.2 won't work with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question, since I have found a solution to my problem. I had previously run `apt-get upgrade` on my system after setting my debian release to jessie. This did not replace python 3.2 though. What did replace it was running `apt-get dist-upgrade`; after that `apt-get autoremove` removed python 3.2. I doubt that this could be a problem, since I hadn't installed any external libraries.

Comment: Yeah, then your system was properly upgraded to use Python 3.4. It is not a matter of *you* installing external libraries, it is the thing that the `python3` symlink is handled and assumed to be handled by the Debian OS itself.