# What to do after upgrading from Python 2 to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, upgrade

Recently I've installed Python 3 after using 2 for quite a while, so I have many libraries for Python that I've installed using `pip`. I've already started using the symlink `python3`, but what else do I need to do to change over?

For example, while I have made the alias `python=python3`, I don't know about the modules I've installed with `pip`. I was using a version of `pip` for Python 2, but does that mean modules were written for Python 2 and not 3? Do I now need to start using `pip3` (or make a corresponding alias `pip=pip3` or `pip=pip3.5`)? If modules were installed using the command `pip`, does that mean I have to reinstall them for Python 3 using `pip3`? If I do need to reinstall them for 3, should I start removing them from my Python 2 env as cleanup?

And another question that seems like it may entail a lot of work: How should I change all my virtual environments for Python projects? They were all Python 2 envs, and now I'm not sure whether it's necessary, useful, or possible to reinstall or upgrade the modules within them to the corresponding ones for Python 3.

Sorry if this seems like a duplicate question - I've searched and only found resources regarding "how to upgrade" rather than "what to do after upgrading". Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't have a broad knowledge about the language and I'm merely grasping it. But you can list the installed modules in pip using python[version] pip list. I think you should keep old modules in Python 2 just in case and It won't correspond with each other versions.

Comment: Are you using Linux? It sounds like you are. Many modern distros ship with both Python 2.7 _and_ 3.4. You should be aware that symlinking `python` to Python 3.4 [breaks dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29905339/2271269). Just live with typing `python3` and `pip3`.

Comment: You will need to install the same packages (modules) for python3 using pip3. However, I would look into virtual environments, and create a virtual environment with the appropriate modules for that project. When you activate a python3 virtual environment you will not need your alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is strongly recommended [*not* to symlink `python` to Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905339/2271269), at least on Debian-based Linux distros. Debian utility scripts use both Python 3 and 2.7 to work (which means you already had a copy of Python 3 somewhere...), and as a consequence Debian-based distributions ship both versions. Symlinking can cause unexpected breakages. This may or may not be true on other systems, however, but with such ambiguity it is probably useful not to try.

   Instead, live with symlinking `python3` to Python 3. Leave `python` alone.
2. `pip` is usually symlinked to the corresponding pip program for 2.7. Use `pip3` to specify you want to use the pip program for Python 3. If you  use `pip`, you'll find modules for Python 3 being installed to Python 2.7 site directories and nothing will work as you expect it to. There should be no reason why you can't symlink `pip` to `pip3`, but I'd still not recommend it - it's better to tread cautiously in this regard.
3. You don't need to change your current virtual environments. Just create new ones with [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), pointing to the correct Python program to use. This is the whole point of virtual environments: to sandbox different Python versions, so that neither of them adversely interact with each other.

   If you have projects you really want to ship to Python 3, I'd recommend using a version control system to back up your current files, and then reproducing them in a new virtual environment configured for Python 3. This is quick, simple and painless.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - I know I shouldn't mess around with symlinks, so instead I simply made the bashrc alias `python=python3`, and was considering also making the alias `pip=pip3` (not a symlink). Are you saying even making an alias is not a good idea also, and I should instead simply keep referring to it as `python3`?